# Finding optimum value for a function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

Suppose you have $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$,

If we can rewrite f as: $f(x)=Kp(x)^\alpha q(x)^\beta$, where, $p,q$ functions, $k$ constant and

$$K'=(p(x)+q(x))'=0,$$

then a candidate for a optimum value for f is the solution of:
$$\dfrac{\alpha}{p(x)}=\dfrac{\beta}{q(x)}$$

I used this method in high-school because one old friend told me years ago and I didn't like to use derivative methods because everyone in my classroom used it. It works fine, there is a proof?

Comment: Any example? Try with $f(x)=4x^2-24x-64$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little bit confused as to why you believe this is really different than simply taking the derivative to find an extreme value?

$$f'(x) = (Kp(x)^\alpha q(x)^\beta)'$$
$$=K(\alpha p(x)^{\alpha -1} q(x)^\beta + \beta p(x)q(x)^{\beta -1} =0$$

Thus 
$$\alpha p(x)^{\alpha -1} q(x)^\beta = -\beta p(x)^{\alpha}q(x)^{\beta -1} $$
Assuming the functions are not 0 at x, we have
$$\frac{\alpha}{p(x)} = - \frac{\beta}{q(x)}$$

Comment: hahaha i've never tried see why this holds, haha thanks